# PDO SQL query in php returning nothing?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a query which should return a single row, I have tested my query in SQL and it runs correctly and gives me a result, but in php it returns a blank array?

This is my php code below

```
    $user = $userArray['user'] = $messageInfo['user'];
    $message = $userArray['usersMessage'] = $messageInfo['message'];

    $getUsersRank = "SELECT rank from users WHERE username = '.$user.'";

    $getUsersRankQuery = $db->prepare($getUsersRank);

    $getUsersRankQuery->execute();

    $rank = $getUsersRankQuery->fetchAll();

    print_r($rank);
```

$userArray is an array like this

```
(
    [user] => kieronapple
    [usersMessage] => hi
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must put your string var value into 2 `'` and remove `.` from your query, you may end the " with ' and it is not true, also the string inside 2 " translated by PHP so you should update your query to be :

```
$getUsersRank = "SELECT rank from users WHERE username = '$user'";
```

Comment: Thank you Gouda, this worked perfectly. Never knew that this was available!